# How can I show chartjs popup like this when I move to point?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chart.js, hover

I have 2 data in datasets. But the timestamp of "day ago" is 1 day slower. Is there any way to make the popup display like in the picture?
[myChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMGli.png)

My source for datasets

```
data: {
          datasets: [{
          label: '{{label}}',
          borderColor: '#FFFF00',
          backgroundColor: '#FFFF00',
          pointBorderColor: '#FFFF00',
          pointBackgroundColor: '#FFFF00',
          pointBorderWidth: 0,
          borderWidth: 2,
          tension: 0.5,
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#000",
          pointHoverBorderColor: "#000",
          data: fetchData(start, end),
        },
        {
          label: '{{label_da}}',
          borderColor: '#F44336',
          backgroundColor: '#F44336',
          pointBorderColor: '#F44336',
          pointBackgroundColor: '#F44336',
          pointBorderWidth: 0,
          borderWidth: 2,
          tension: 0.5,
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#000",
          pointHoverBorderColor: "#000",
          data: fetchData_da(start, end),
        }]
      },
```